# Controlled Z gate using Pauli rotation operators and Z tensor product Z

Tags: circuit-construction, pauli-gates

I am trying to construct a controlled Z gate using elementary gates.  This is what I have so far: \begin{pmatrix}
-i & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix}
can someone help me figure out how to get rid of the unwanted phase shift?

I can use combinations of a single-qubit Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\Omega_x\hat{X}+\frac{1}{2}\Omega_y\hat{Y}+\frac{1}{2}\Omega_z\hat{Z}$ and $\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\Omega_{zz}\hat{Z}\otimes\hat{Z}$. I can construct the $\hat{I}\otimes\hat{H}$ matrix above but I cannot construct the CNOT gate so far.

Comment: Are you looking for ways to make a $CZ$ gate as the evolution under these Hamiltonians? (i.e. $CZ = exp(H_{cons})$ with $H_{cons}$ some constructed Hamiltonian from these two base Hamiltonians? In that case check what is $exp(\frac{1}{2}\Omega_{zz}Z \otimes Z)$ and equate this to the $CZ$ gate; you will find that they are equal for some $\Omega_{zz}$.

Comment: If you in fact want an identity like $CZ = H_{cons}$ with $H_{cons}$ some constructed Hamiltonian from these two base Hamiltonians, it will be harder to make this, as $CZ$ is a unitary operation, and these wo Hamiltonians are Hermitian, which might give you some problems to construct them.

Comment: What I'm saying is, you ask how to make the $CZ$ using _gates_ from two base elements, but you provide two _Hamiltonians_, which are generally speaking not (unitary) gates - they invoke unitary operations through the Schrodinger equation, where $U = exp(H)$.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "elementary gates". Using only Pauli gates (that is, using only $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ gates), you cannot build a controlled $Z$ gate. One way to prove it is simply to show that the controlled $Z$ gate cannot be written as $A\otimes B$, with $A$ and $B$ being unitary matrices.

However, if we allow ourselves to use gates from the Clifford group, it is easy to build a controlled $Z$ gate using $I\otimes H$ gates and a CNOT gate:
$$\begin{align}(I\otimes H)\mathsf{C}X(I\otimes H) &= \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\\&=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
Note that the circuit we are building is a CNOT applied on the second qubit, controlled by the first one, and surrounded by two $H$ gates on the second qubit.

It is however way easier to reason on the basis states. A common relation that may be useful to know is $HXH=Z$. Thus, if the first qubit is in state $|0\rangle$, we apply on the second qubit $HH=I$, but if the first qubit is in state $|1\rangle$, we apply $HXH=Z$, which is the behavior of a controlled-$Z$ gate.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tristan.  I am able to use the Pauli gates and a Hamiltonian of the form $ \hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\theta\hat{Z}\otimes\hat{Z} $.  I am not sure if I can construct the same matrices in the Clifford group from these.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Based on what Tristan has said, I wonder if the problem is solvable since all of the matrices are unitary.

Comment: @Anne can you develop about how you are allowed to use this Hamiltonian directly in your question? The beginning of my answer supposed that you could only use one-qubit gates (since I thought you were only allowed to use Pauli gates).